# What's the difference between next two snippets?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am a newbie to MFC , and come up to these two snippets. They look different, but both work, I just do not understand why?
Helps. Thanks a lot.

// snippet 1

```
BOOL CMainApp::InitInstance()

{       
  CMainFrame *wnd = new CMainFrame();    
  m_pMainWnd = wnd;     
  wnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);    
  wnd->UpdateWindow();    

  return true;    
}
```

// snippet 2

```
BOOL CMainApp::InitInstance()

{    
    CMainFrame wnd;
    wnd.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    wnd.UpdateWindow();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply the difference between staticly-assigned objects and dynamically-assigned objects, together with how pointers work.

Your first snippet dynamically allocates a new `CMainFrame` object, which is default-constructed. Its address in memory is stored in the pointer `wnd`, and then in the member variable `m_pMainWnd`. You then invoke `ShowWindow` and `UpdateWindow` on the object pointed to by `wnd`

In snippet two, you statically allocate a `CMainFrame` object local to the function, then invoke `ShowWindow` and `UpdateWindow` on that object.

Note that there is a difference, though - in the first snippet the `CMainFrame` object exists beyond the end of the function; in the second, it's destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your helpful explanations.It really helps me a lot. :)

Comment: @ActuallyIAmTheBest - no worries. Remember you can give credit for helpful answers by clicking the up-arrow next to the answer; and mark one answer as "correct" by clicking the big check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the main difference is that in the first case you are dynamically allocating memory for CMainFrame whereas in the second case you seem to be creating that object as a local variable.

I am surprised the second case doesn't crash since **wnd** gets destroyed when **InitInstance** finish its execution.

In the first snippet you keep this window at the allocated memory which reference seems to be kept at **m_pMainWnd** attribute: m_pMainWnd. At leat the new window is not destroyed at the end of InitInstance.

Comment: @ActuallyIAmTheBest You did't accepted my answer so, if you find it useful remember to upvote it, if you want, when your reputation allows it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, sorry now, and I will remember to upvote yours when my reputation allows me to .